# making an image half of it's size in Matlab without using Resize

Tags: matlab, resize, compression

that's a code my prof said but I don't understand it. 
`A=imread('cameraman'); i=1:4:256; T=A(i,i); imshow(A); figure; imshow(T);`

Why does the image just become smaller, and details are not omitted?

Answer (score 2):

Details **are** being omitted. I'm assuming from the code that the image is 256x256.
The indexing variable `i` is being defined with a step of 4, meaning it goes something like this:

```
i = [1 5 9 13 ... 256];
```

Then, it is used to index both the row and columns of the matrix `A` to create a new matrix `T`.
That's why the new image is smaller; T only contains data points from A that are indexed by `i`.

As an exercise I recommend varying the step to see how the resulting image changes. Change the step to 1 and you will see that both images are the same size. Change the step to 8 and you will see that the second image is now even smaller than before.

Comment: Details are being omitted __and__ [aliased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)